# Creating a shallow copy of an instance of a class inheriting from collections.OrderedDict

Tags: python

I have a class inheriting from `collections.OrderedDict` with an initializer that takes a positional argument *without default*. My goal is to create a *shallow* copy of the instance. However, my initial naive approach below does not work and raises a type error as the positional argument must be supplied when building the new instance.

```
class B(collections.OrderedDict):

def __init__(self, whatever):
    super().__init__()
    self.whatever = whatever

b = B(3)
b.update({'a':1})
print(b.copy())
```

A solution could be to add:

```
def copy(self):
    new = collections.OrderedDict(self)
    new.whatever = self.whatever
    return new
```

But this becomes unwieldy when the number of attribute grows. Is there a better, more direct solution to this problem?

**EDIT**:
I am using Python 3.5

Comment: If we are only concerned about instance attributes then you could do: `new.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)` in `copy()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The problem is that even if I do it like that, I will not get an object of class B back.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) library:

```
copied_object = copy.copy(b)
```

Comment: This does not work in Python 2, which I assume the OP is using, because OP's original method of `.copy()` would have worked in Python 3.

Comment: @Karin I'm actually using Python 3.

Comment: @Dominik That's strange - when I run your code in Python 3 I do not get a TypeError. However, I do get one in Python 2.

Comment: This won't work either, the new instance would expect the positional argument `whatever` to be passed, and `copy.copy()` won't do that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary In deed, it does not work. I suspect it implicitly calls the copy() method.